# How to convert character type date to date type in SAS

Tags: datetime, sas, type-conversion

I have a character variable in the form of "Jan-17" in my table and would like to convert it to date type. Does anyone what kind of date form this is and how I could go about converting it? Thank you.

Comment: You have not provided enough information.  It could mean the seventeenth of January for some unspecified year.  It might mean some day in January of year 17 in some unspecified century.  What do the other values look like?  What is a reasonable range of dates for the data you are working with?

Comment: The variable is a column with dates in the form of month-year. So, Jan-17 would be January 2017, Apr-18 would be April 2018 and so on. I want to convert the column into date format but I'm not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

SAS date variables are stored as number of days since Jan 1, 1960.  For a variable that is Month and Year only, you'd need to pick a day - many choose the 1st, some the 15th or 30th/31st, depending on your business rules.

Either way, you can use the [`input`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm) function as a starting place.  You need to know the [informat](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm) - the instructions for how to translate characters to numbers.  In your case, `MONYY6.` will likely work, though you can also try `ANYDATEDTE.` to let SAS guess the date informat to use.

Then, if needed, you can adjust the date it chose based on your business rules using the [intnx function](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm), which allows you to adjust it to the 15th or end of month if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [INPUT()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lefunctionsref/p19en16vskd2vhn1vwmxpxnglxxs.htm) function with the correct informat.

```
data have;
date_char = 'Jan-17';
run;

data want;
set have;
date_dt = input(date_char, monyy6.);

format date_dt date9.;
run;
```

```
01JAN2017
```